# How to implement the `Get` trait for a `Pallet<T>`?

Tags: frame, frontier, evm, traits, generics

I'm writing a pallet that implements [`evm::executor::stack::PrecompileSet`](https://docs.rs/evm/0.37.0/evm/executor/stack/trait.PrecompileSet.html).

The goal is to use this pallet in conjunction with Frontier's `pallet-evm`, [which has the following types in its `Config` trait](https://github.com/paritytech/frontier/blob/58c568964dc32dd96153b7d113ac2df58d27de2b/frame/evm/src/lib.rs#LL138C8-L138C21):

```
type PrecompilesType: PrecompileSet;
type PrecompilesValue: Get<Self::PrecompilesType>;
```

While writing a mock environment for unit testing the pallet I'm writing, I'm struggling to make the compiler happy for `PrecompilesValue`:

```
parameter_types! {
    ...
    pub MockPrecompiles: crate::Pallet<Test> = // ?
}
impl pallet_evm::Config for Test {
    ...
    type PrecompilesType = crate::Pallet<Test>;
    type PrecompilesValue = MockPrecompiles;
    ...
}
```

It seems non-trivial to use the `parameter_types!` macro to get an appropriate `impl<T: Config> Get<T> for Pallet<T>`. With a blind trial-and-error strategy I ran into this error message:

```
error[E0423]: cannot initialize a tuple struct which contains private fields
   --> frame/evm-precompile/src/mock.rs:136:45
    |
136 |     pub MockPrecompiles: crate::Pallet<Test> = crate::Pallet(PhantomData::<Test>);
    |                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

is it possible to set `MockPrecompiles`/`PrecompilesValue` in this Runtime configuration?

Comment: `what is the appropriate Rust syntax to set MockPrecompiles/PrecompilesValue in this Runtime configuration?`

your question is not completely understandable. Rust aside, what should `PrecompilesValue` be, just when thinking about it conceptually?

Comment: `pub MockPrecompiles: crate::Pallet<Test> = crate::Pallet(PhantomData::<Test>);` pallet structs are never meant to be instantiated, I find it hardly that you will be able to find a way around this.

Comment: as defined in `pallet-evm`: `type PrecompilesValue: Get<Self::PrecompilesType>`, and I set `type PrecompilesType = crate::Pallet<Test>`

Comment: "as defined in pallet-evm.." Rephrasing what I said, I am asking what this type should be all Rust details aside, at a conceptual level. What does it mean and where should it come from?

Comment: this type represents the set of precompiles that `pallet-evm` will be able to execute... it is meant to be a custom implementation for each runtime https://github.com/paritytech/frontier/blob/8a5492f23925b0d7d2607e943982d90da017c3f2/template/runtime/src/precompiles.rs#L30

Answer (score 1):

Your question makes me confused.

But to your question title.

You could simply do this:

https://github.com/darwinia-network/darwinia/blob/61c6de47e5ef11e1842d1d35476bfb699ef2cd58/pallet/deposit/src/lib.rs#L387-L400

https://github.com/darwinia-network/darwinia/blob/61c6de47e5ef11e1842d1d35476bfb699ef2cd58/runtime/darwinia/src/pallets/staking.rs#L76

I implement the `Stake` for `darwinia_deposit::Pallet<T>` and pass it to the other pallet's configuration as a param. And you can simply replace the `Stake` with `Get`.